# django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: App_useraccount

Tags: python, django

```
from django.db import models
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (AbstractBaseUser,
                                        BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin )


class MyAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, first_name, last_name, email,username,password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('user must have an email address')
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('user must have an username')

        user = self.model(
            email = self.normalize_email(email),
            username = username,
            first_name = first_name,
            last_name = last_name,
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, first_name, last_name,username, email, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            email = self.normalize_email(email),
            username = username,
            password = password,
            first_name = first_name,
            last_name = last_name
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_active = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superadmin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

class UserAccount(AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin):
    first_name      = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    last_name       = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    username        = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
    email           = models.EmailField(max_length=64, unique=True)
    state           = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    city            = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    phone_number    = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    address         = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    dob             = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    gender          = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    min_salary      = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    max_salary      = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    profile_pic     = models.ImageField(upload_to='app/img/condidate')

    # required_fields

    date_joined     = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_login      = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_admin        = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff        = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active       = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superadmin   = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD  = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username','first_name','last_name']

    objects = MyAccountManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, add_label):
        return True

class Company(models.Model):
    user_id      = models.ForeignKey(UserAccount, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post_by      = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    date_of_post = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    discription  = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    contact      = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    address      = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    logo_pic     = models.ImageField(upload_to="app/img/company")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Companies'

**forms.py**

    from django import forms
    from .models import UserAccount
    
    class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
        password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
            'placeholder': 'Enter Password'
        }))
        confirm_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
            'placeholder': 'Confirm Password'
        }))
        class Meta:
            model  = UserAccount
            fields = ['first_name','last_name','email','phone_number','password']
    
        def clean(self):
            cleaned_data = super(RegistrationForm, self).clean()
            password = cleaned_data.get('password')
            confirm_password = cleaned_data.get('confirm_password')
    
            if password != confirm_password:
                raise forms.ValidationError('Password does not match!') 
    
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(RegistrationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['first_name'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] =  'Enter Your First Name'
            self.fields['last_name'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] =  'Enter Your last Name'
            self.fields['email'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] =  'Enter Your Email Address'
            self.fields['phone_number'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] =  'Enter Your Phone Number'
    
            for field in self.fields:
                self.fields[field].widget.attrs['class'] =  'form-control'
```

**i want to add some fields to my models so i deleted the sqlite3 database and initial001 file then added extra fields to existing models and run the makemigration and migrate when i run createsuperuser it will showing this error

```
(myenv) C:\Users\Omkar\JobFind_Project\omkar>py manage.py createsuperuser
Email: sms88864@gmail.com       
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Omkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 89, in _execute  
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Omkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 357, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: App_useraccount

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Omkar\JobFind_Project\omkar\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Omkar\JobFind_Project\omkar\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Omkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Omkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Omkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 402, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Omkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 88, in execute
    return super().execute(*args, **options)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Omkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 448, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Omkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 130, in handle
    error_msg = self._validate_username(
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Omkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 297, in _validate_username
    self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database).get_by_natural_key(
  File "C:\Users\Omkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 46, in get_by_natural_key
    return self.get(**{self.model.USERNAME_FIELD: username})
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Omkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Omkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 646, in get        
    num = len(clone)
          ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Omkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 376, in __len__    
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\Omkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1866, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Omkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 87, in __iter__    
    results = compiler.execute_sql(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Omkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1398, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Omkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 103, in execute  
    return super().execute(sql, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Omkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 67, in execute   
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Omkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 80, in _execute_with_wrappers
  File "C:\Users\Omkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 89, in _execute  
  File "C:\Users\Omkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 89, in _execute  
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  File "C:\Users\Omkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 357, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: App_useraccount

(myenv) C:\Users\Omkar\JobFind_Project\omkar>

(myenv) C:\Users\Omkar\JobFind_Project\omkar>py manage.py makemigrations 
No changes detected

(myenv) C:\Users\Omkar\JobFind_Project\omkar>py manage.py migrate        
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.

(myenv) C:\Users\Omkar\JobFind_Project\omkar>py manage.py createsuperuser
Email: sms88864@gmail.com
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Omkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 89, in _execute  
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Omkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 357, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: App_useraccount

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Omkar\JobFind_Project\omkar\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Omkar\JobFind_Project\omkar\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Omkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Omkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Omkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 402, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Omkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 88, in execute
    return super().execute(*args, **options)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Omkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 448, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Omkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 130, in handle
    error_msg = self._validate_username(
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Omkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 297, in _validate_username
    self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database).get_by_natural_key(
  File "C:\Users\Omkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 46, in get_by_natural_key
    return self.get(**{self.model.USERNAME_FIELD: username})
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Omkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Omkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 646, in get
    num = len(clone)
          ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Omkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 376, in __len__    
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\Omkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1866, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Omkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 357, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: App_useraccount
```

**

i added extra fields to that models so want to run migrate and makemigrate and createsuperuser successfully

Answer (score 0):

1. Find the last good state where your database was working.
2. Comment out all the new models.py file changes
3. Delete all the files from the migrations folder.
4. Truncate django_migrations table
5. Run python manage.py makemigrations
6. Run python manage.py migrate --fake
7. Uncomment the changes which you did in step 2.
8. Run python manage.py makemigrations
9. Run python manage.py migrate